# Tmux - Cannot use "Shift + arrows" to switch window on Mac OS

Tags: macos, tmux

Got recently a Mac computer for work and beeing a Tmux fan I did installed it with my favorite plugins and .tmux.conf file that I use on my personnal Linux machine.

After some tweaking to make it usable on Mac OS, the only thing that's still not working is my shortcut to switch window using "Shift + arrow" doesn't work on this Mac computer.

I put this into my .tmux.conf :

```
# Set this on Mac OS

set-option -g -w xterm-keys on

# Shift arrow to switch windows 

bind -n S-Left previous-window
bind -n S-Right next-window
```

My guess is that the Shift key is being used by something. when I do

```
tmux list-keys | grep "S-"
```

Here is the output:

```
bind-key -r -T prefix       S-Up                 refresh-client -U 10
bind-key -r -T prefix       S-Down               refresh-client -D 10
bind-key -r -T prefix       S-Left               refresh-client -L 10
bind-key -r -T prefix       S-Right              refresh-client -R 10
bind-key    -T root         S-Left               previous-window
bind-key    -T root         S-Right              next-window
```

I tried to unbind as this:

```
unbind-key S-Left
unbind-key S-Right
```

but still, "shift+arrow" doesn't do anything.

Do you guys have any idea how to solve this ?

Thanks!

Xzi.

Comment: Try 'sudo showkey' to see if your terminal emulator is even receiving the key. If nothing shows up when you press the related hotkeys then you need to figure out how to unbind the key in your terminal emulator.

Comment: Please clarify: by previous/next "window" do you mean previous/next "window within this application" (like cmd+` in Finder), or previous/next "application" (like cmd+tab) or what?

Comment: @jwc845 your idea was good but 'sudo showkey' doesn't work on mac.

Comment: @blalond : To clarify I mean previous / next window within the Tmux application. Therefore, moving to previous / next windows within a tmux's session.

Answer (score 0):

I used OSX a few years back and ran into the same issue but was able to resolve it. I don't use OSX now, so I am posting this solution based on what I remember.

I think, first you need to disable the `Shift+arrow` keybinding from your terminal preferences, or the OSX system preferences. Then, you need to add a new keybinding for `Shift+arrow` keys (in your terminal preferences) to map the desired byobu commands.

Based on https://github.com/tmux/tmux/blob/master/tty-keys.c, `Shift+Up` maps to `\033[a`. So, in the terminal preference, add a new keybinding for `Shift+Up` and add the command as: `Escape Sequence` + `[a`. Do the same for other `Shift+arrow` keys.

Note that I am posting this from what I vaguely remember. But the solution was definitely along these lines. Try it out with some other modifications and let us know what worked for you.

Comment: Alright, I'll try it. Thanks

Comment: I could not make it work with your solution above ( maybe an issue on my end ) however, I did up to date my system from 10.14 to 10.15 and now it is working out of the box ... go figure :) anyways, thank you for you suggestion.